# UIAlertController Warning Message

Tags: ios8, uialertcontroller, presentviewcontroller, uialertaction

I am using the below code for UIAlertController in my project.

```
if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]floatValue] >= 8.0){

            UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                          alertControllerWithTitle:@"Input Error"
                                          message:@"Please enter a valid email."
                                          preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            UIAlertAction* okAction = [UIAlertAction
                                       actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                                       style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                       handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                       {
                                           [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                                       }];

            [alert addAction:okAction];

            [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
        else
        {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Input Error"
                                                            message:@"Please enter a valid email"
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertView show];
        }
```

I am getting the below waring message:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7f8da58df1f0>  on <MBComplaintsViewController: 0x7f8da36454d0> which is already presenting (null)
```

Kindly guide me how to properly use UIAlertController using Objective C.

Thanks,
Abin Koshy Cheriyan

Comment: I have created a Github project for the same which you can use to resolve the issue: https://github.com/AgarwalMilan/MAAlertPresenter

Answer (score 1):

Yes as per @Alexander you should not be dismissing the alert controller like this explicitly.

As per an apple engineer a new window gets added each time an UIAlertController is displayed so when we go for dismissing it the window is still there though the alert controller disappears.

So there are two ways to handle this -

**Way 1 - No explicit dismiss**
Do not explicitly dismiss the UIAlertController, let it be done by the user

**Way 2 - Use your own window**
Simply create a category on UIAertController
Here is the sample code - 
**.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIAlertController (MyAdditions)

@property(nonatomic,strong) UIWindow *alertWindow;

-(void)show;

@end
```

In **.m**

```
#import "UIAlertController+MyAdditions.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@implementation UIAlertController (MyAdditions)

@dynamic alertWindow;

- (void)setAlertWindow:(UIWindow *)alertWindow {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(alertWindow), alertWindow, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

- (UIWindow *)alertWindow {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(alertWindow));
}

- (void)show {
    self.alertWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    self.alertWindow.rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    // window level = topmost + 1
    UIWindow *topWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows.lastObject;
    self.alertWindow.windowLevel = topWindow.windowLevel + 1;

    [self.alertWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self.alertWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:self animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)hide {
    self.alertWindow.hidden = YES;
    self.alertWindow = nil;
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    // just to ensure the window gets desroyed
    self.alertWindow.hidden = YES;
    self.alertWindow = nil;
}
```

To show the alert controller

```
UIAlertCntroller *alert = ## initialisation##;
// will show the alert
[alert show];

//to dismiss 
[alert hide];
```

<strike>[alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];</strike>

Even you can checkout one of my sample implementation [here](https://github.com/Sameeran92/POCs-/tree/AlertControllerPOC/AlertController%20Trial)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your problem, but you shouldn't do that

```
handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                       {
                                           [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                                       }];
```

It will be anyway dismissed on any of your `actions`.